# xCode Crashing When Running Application

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time I try to run an iOS application in Xcode it crashes. I have tried restarting my machine, running the application on both physical hardware and emulators, and clearing out the `xcuserdata` folder from the xcodeproj package. With each of these attempt, Xcode immediately crashes when I press the run button or type "cmd + R".

I've included the crash report below for more information. I am running OSX 10.11 and Xcode version 7.0.1 (7A1001). Has anyone else had any luck resolving this problem?

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 7A1001
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8228/IDEKit/Application/IDEWindowMenuController.m:101
Details:  itemName should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
Object:   <IDEWindowMenuController>
Method:   +titleForItemWithURL:name:parentLocations:presentedParentLocationCount:includeIconInTitles:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbaca619830>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010ccc6904 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010b88f22e _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010b88f445 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010cb36d56 +[IDEWindowMenuController titleForItemWithURL:name:parentLocations:presentedParentLocationCount:includeIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  4  0x000000010d0455f6 __90+[IDEWindowMenuController _createAttributedTitlesForItemDictionaries:includeIconInTitles:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  5  0x00007fff9c0aaa96 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x00007fff9c0aa929 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
  7  0x000000010caa52cb +[IDEWindowMenuController _createAttributedTitlesForItemDictionaries:includeIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x000000010caa44a1 -[IDEWindowMenuController _windowMenuItemsWithIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  9  0x000000010caa612b -[IDEApplication menuNeedsUpdate:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x00007fff96d843f4 -[NSMenu _populateFromDelegateWithEventRef:] (in AppKit)
 11  0x00007fff96d80999 -[NSMenu _populateWithEventRef:] (in AppKit)
 12  0x00007fff96d83551 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _carbonPopulateEvent:handlerCallRef:] (in AppKit)
 13  0x00007fff96d8323d NSSLMMenuEventHandler (in AppKit)
 14  0x00007fff8f8e298e DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 15  0x00007fff8f8e1e18 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) (in HIToolbox)
 16  0x00007fff8f8e1c7b SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions (in HIToolbox)
 17  0x00007fff8f9293cb SendMenuPopulate(MenuData*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, unsigned int, double, unsigned int, OpaqueEventRef*, unsigned char, unsigned char*) (in HIToolbox)
 18  0x00007fff8f929174 PopulateMenu(MenuData*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, CheckMenuData*, unsigned int, double) (in HIToolbox)
 19  0x00007fff8f92881b Check1MenuForKeyEvent(MenuData*, CheckMenuData*) (in HIToolbox)
 20  0x00007fff8f927dd3 CheckMenusForKeyEvent(MenuData*, CheckMenuData*) (in HIToolbox)
 21  0x00007fff8f9278c0 _IsMenuKeyEvent(MenuData*, OpaqueEventRef*, unsigned int, MenuData**, unsigned short*) (in HIToolbox)
 22  0x00007fff8f9275d4 IsMenuKeyEvent (in HIToolbox)
 23  0x00007fff96d82e76 +[NSCarbonMenuImpl _menuItemWithKeyEquivalentMatchingEventRef:inMenu:] (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff96d82c00 _NSFindMenuItemMatchingCommandKeyEvent (in AppKit)
 25  0x00007fff96d6e2cf _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent (in AppKit)
 26  0x00007fff96be3281 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff96be2369 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 28  0x000000010be6049b -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 29  0x00007fff96bd6ecc -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff96ba0162 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff9a78e5ad start (in libdyld.dylib)
```

Comment: Apple is up to an official / production build of Xcode 7.1.1 now.  What happens when you try your app under that simulator?

Comment: I'm also getting the same crash in Xcode 7.1.1 after launch.

Comment: I also getting the same behavior even after updating. Reverting to a previous commit of the project fixed this issue but is far from idea.

Answer (score 7):

I was seeing the same behaviour. I found [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39603) on the Apple Developer site which explained what to do: close any tabs in your Xcode project which have an empty title. Fixed the problem for me, and this would explain why reverting resolved the problem. Somehow the project file had become corrupted.